# Changing the spelling of "G-d" and Halachic erasure

Tags: halacha, words, shemos-sacred-names, english

Is there a problem of "erasing the name of HaShem" if you erase the English word spelled G-o-d, and if so, is there then a problem of erasing it in order to spell it in a more acceptable way (such as G-d), *and if so*, is there a problem of simply *changing* the spelling by erasing the 'o' and replacing it with a '-'?

Comment: If erasing the whole word "God" to change it is forbidden, then erasing any letter of it is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

No. There isn't really an issue in writing or erasing 'God'

See: http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/god-or-g-d.html

> There is no issue in writing or printing Hashem’s name properly, providing one knows that it won’t be destroyed.
>
> Rambam (Yesodei Hatorah 6:1) writes that there are 7 sheimos (names of Hashem) that mustn’t be erased. There is no issur in erasing a kinui (moniker) such as chanun or rachum, etc. R’ Akiva Eiger (YD 276:9 quoting the Tashbetz) writes that as translations of sheimos have the status of kinuim, there is no issur in erasing them either.
>
> The Shach (YD 179:11) writes that Hashem’s name in a foreign language is not considered sheimos and thus may be erased. Likewise, the Mishna Berura (85:10) writes that the issur only applies to erasing sheimos in Hebrew (See Minchas Chinuch 437:5).
>
> Nonetheless, the Aruch Hashulchan (CM 27:3) urges people to be extra particular when writing letters with sheimos even in a foreign language.
>
> Thus, while it is not strictly forbidden to write or erase the word ‘God’, it is good practice to write ‘G-d’ and such writings must still be treated with respect. Thus, rather than thrown in the bin, a paper containing the word ‘God’ should be recycled with other documents, or wrapped before disposal (See Igros Moshe OC 4:39).