# Spelling "Lord" like "L-rd"?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

Is writing "L-rd" with a hyphen, either when reading יהוה or in general, also a Jewish custom? I first saw it it on some messianic website and thought it's rather missing the point and whole context of writing *G-d* with a hyphen, but since then I've seen people very occasionally using it in a Jewish context.

Since some people won't use *Adonai* in casual speech and will instead use *Adoshem* out of respect, it could be this with extra steps? It seems like it's conflating the two somewhat different customs, though.

Comment: What are the two customs at play here exactly?

Comment: Replacing God with G-d and Adonai with Adoshem seem to me to be slightly different in nature - the first one is an explicit nod to the prohibition on desecrating the name of God any context, the second one seems to be a more vague custom broadly aimed at underlining the distinction between casual and prayer language.

Comment: Both examples are examples that we do not say Hashems name in vain. Hence why some spell it with a "-".

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36675/why-are-jews-so-meticulous-about-not-saying-writing-god/59268#59268