# Is using "god" as a common noun assur?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

In the English language, it is not uncommon to hear a person being referred to as "the god of x". Where x can be a skill or specialty like "software engineering", "the god of math" etc.

Is there any issur in using the word "god", which is a homophone with the term "God", which [according to the Mishna Berurah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59268/11845)  may have the status of a holy name.

I'm thinking in terms of minimizing the awe around God's name.

Comment: 100% sinful, I just know it like I can literally feel it

Comment: Either you're calling the programmer big-G G-d, which is idolatrous; or you're calling him a little-g god, which means we think he's false. Even if the latter, not a good habit.

Comment: 100% pure evil, no way around it (Exodus 20:3).