# "Penny Press" machines and erasing G-d's name

Tags: halacha, money, shemos-sacred-names

<sub>**NOTE**: while a bit similar to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15349/changing-the-spelling-of-g-d-and-halachic-erasure), they're not entirely the same. For example: this question is more of a "*grama*"/ indirect causation of erasing G-d's name (via pushing a button) vs. a person knowingly and actively erasing it</sub>

---

There are these "Penny Press" machines where one puts in a couple quarters and a penny, pushes a button, and the machine squashes the penny into a collectible design.

Here's what such a machine looks like:

[image]

**My question**

Since pennies have "[In G-d We Trust](https://www.moderncoinsandbanknotes.com/products/2019-w-lincoln-penny-union-shield-cent-proof-single-coin-sealed-in-mint-packaging?variant=16388424466522&currency=USD&utm_campaign=gs-2018-12-20&utm_source=google&utm_medium=smart_campaign)" inscribed on them, **would this be allowed as it could be considered "erasing G-d's name?"**

Comment: MB 334:52 : עם האזכרות - שכיון שהם אדוקים בודאי כתבו אותן לשם ע"ג ומכאן יש להזהיר על אותן מטבעות של זהב וכסף שטבעו אותן האדוקין לשם ע"ג שאסורים לתלותם על הס"ת וגם אין להחזיק אותם ברשותו אלא יתיכם מיד כדי שלא יהיה שום זכרון למעשיהם [ב"ח וט"ז] והרב מו"ה יהודא מילר נסתפק אי מותר להתיכן שמא אינם מינים לע"ג ובתשובת חות יאיר סימן שט"ז מתיר להתיך המטבעות של שם בן ד' שנעשים במדינות שוויידן מטעם כי נטבעו להוציאם והו"ל כאלו נכתבו בפירוש לשם חול וכן משמע בפמ"ג ע"ש. עוד כתב מה שנוהגין באיזה קהלות כשמברכין חולה וגובין מעות מכל אחד ומניחין הכלי עם המעות לתוך ארון הקודש לא יפה עושין ע"ש ...

Comment: @sam thanks! Want to add in the English translation and make this an answer?

Comment: I would think not since the name referring to G-d in pennies is usually associated with the Christian god. In any event, it probably would be best to stay away from Penny Presses. Unless you invent one which doesn't squash the name of G-d.